# Istio metrics destination unknown

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, spiffe

**Scenario**

Istio version 1.5.0 ontop of EKS 1.14.
Enabled components:

- Base
- Pilot

**NOTE** Istio 1.5.0 deprecates Mixer, moved to telemetry v2, which happens inside the envoy proxy sidecar.

I want to use Istio to support some metrics out of the box.

Here's the flow

my computer -> Gateway -> Virtual Service A -> Virtual Service B

I made sure that:

1. K8s Service objects have label `app`
2. K8s Deployment objects and their pod templates have label `app`

I can run the flow just fine, which means the configurations are correct.

The problem is with telemetry.

```
istio_requests_total{connection_security_policy="unknown",destination_app="unknown",destination_canonical_revision="latest",destination_canonical_service="unknown",destination_principal="spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default",destination_service="svcb.default.svc.cluster.local",destination_service_name="svcb.default.svc.cluster.local",destination_service_namespace="unknown",destination_version="unknown",destination_workload="unknown",destination_workload_namespace="unknown",grpc_response_status="0",instance="10.2.55.80:15090",job="envoy-stats",namespace="default",pod_name="svca-77969dc86b-964p5",reporter="source",request_protocol="grpc",response_code="200",response_flags="-",source_app="svca",source_canonical_revision="latest",source_canonical_service="svca",source_principal="spiffe://cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default",source_version="unknown",source_workload="svca",source_workload_namespace="default"}
```

**Question**

1. Why are most `destination-*` labels `unknown`?
2. The [official istio mesh dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/7639) typically filter metrics by `reporter=destination`. Why do all of my `istio_requests_total` series have `reporter=source`?

Comment: Are you sure that your service B has its sidecar proxy correctly started? I think it doesn't because 1/ not having telemetry with `reporter=destination` means it doesn't report telemetry when it receives a request (it should) and 2/ namespace and service name being "unknown" indicate it isn't being considered as part of the mesh.

Comment: Thank you. I know my sidecar proxy was working in service B (its pods have the proxy container running and I can gather the log as you could see). I considered 'it isn't being considered as part of the mesh' but I'm not sure where I went wrong. I thought service b is part of the mesh since I created a virtual service for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh right, after much digging, [here's the answer](https://istio.io/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/).

> Istio supports proxying all TCP traffic by default, but in order to provide additional capabilities, such as routing and rich metrics, the protocol must be determined. This can be done automatically or explicitly specified

I didn't specify the port name in my Service resource. Once I did that, the problem is resolved.